# I want to understand something with BigNumber assertions

Tags: vyper, brownie, assert, test

I have create a truffle project with a smartcontract and a test file.

Here is an extract of the test file:

```
expect(ret).to.be.bignumber.equal(new BN('42'));
```

ret is a value returned by a smartcontract's function i want to test. It is an uint256 value: 42.

It works fine but I have some questions in order to understand:

- Why should i work with BN library ? Javascript does not support uint256 ? What is the difference with this (it works too):

  ```
   assert.equal(ret, 42);
  ```
- Why 42 must be written as a string in BN constructor ? This is an integer, not a string...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of small numbers you don't have to use any BigNumber library.

The problem is that if you don't use a BigNumber library with your tests with small numbers, the same code won't work anymore if you want to use bigger numbers. So it's mostly good practice to already use BigNumbers, no matter whether you use small or big numbers.

Comment: do you know the javascript limit ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER